# mongoose help, why i'm getting null?

Tags: angular, mongoose

I'm trying to get item._id because I'm getting it as an array from req.body.items.
i need each item as a seperate one to push it to my new order._items array.

```js
     app.post('/orders/:userEmail/',(req,res)=>{
         let itemNew=new Item();
          let orderNew=new Order();
          let itemArray=req.body.items;
          
         async function getItem(item) {
            try {
              const itemp = await Item
                .findOne({ Id: item });
              return itemp;
            }
            catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
        }
    
        for(let item of itemArray ){
           getItem (item)
              .then(ItemReturned=> {
                orderNew._items(ItemReturned) **//here i get the correct item**
              });
              console.log("orderNew._items-----"+orderNew._items);**//here i get null**
              }
         }
```

Comment: Looks like `console.log("orderNew._items-----"+orderNew._items)` the statement will be executed before the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your `console.log("orderNew._items-----"+orderNew._items);` statement in `then` block.

```js
    for(let item of itemArray ){
       getItem (item)
          .then(ItemReturned=> {
            orderNew._items(ItemReturned)
            console.log("orderNew._items-----"+orderNew._items);
          });
          }
     }
```

Because when the `node` interpreter see `.then()` callback it push the callback to the callback queue and continue the execution, while at this time your callback is not ready and your `console.log()` prints null.

Comment: i guessed this is the issue but i couldent resolve it.
you have a proposal? what sould i do?

Comment: i manage to get an answer. but i'm getting [object Promise]. i dodnt know how to handele this.

Comment: What is the type of `ItemReturned`

Comment: it sould be from Item type. that it what i get from the async function getItem

Comment: What do you exactly wanna do. If you want to save an order which has `_items` array the better way is to do `orderNew = new Order({_items: ItemReturned})` then save it `orderNew.save()`.

Comment: Additionally you can use `await` to see what is the `[object Promise]` exactly is.

Comment: Here is a link to read more about `async/await` https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: it is still not working. i want to create an order base on req.body.items i get.
to do that i need to look for thos items _id to push it to my order._items array.

Comment: i' tried this code: 
 async function getItem(item) {
  try {
    const itemp = await Item.findOne({ Id: item });
    return itemp;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
  for(let item of itemArray ){
    getItem(item).then(function(itemp) {
      console.log("karin--"+itemp);
      orderNew = new Order({_items: itemp})
    });

Comment: and this is my answer `[object Promise]`